Is it allowed to write a vacuous truth using the present tense but not the past subjunctive?
My experience of learning English grammar is that I should use the subjunctive form when I write an unrealistic event (said by my teacher and several resources that I read long time ago).
The sentence is:

If Tokyo is in Spain, then the Eiffel Tower is in Bolivia.

I took that sentence right from this intereseting topic about a vacuous truth. It's well-known that Tokyo IS in Japan, that means, writing Tokyo is in Spain is unrealistic, then why would the writer not write this way:

If tokyo were in Spain, then the Eiffel Towers were in Bolivia.

Or are those just the same? That means the second suggestion of mine is allowed?
Please elaborate your answer as I want to deepen my knowledge about subjunctive.
Thank you very much in advance.

There's nothing wrong with your original sentence. But if you wanted to use the subjunctive, then the correct sentence would be "If Tokyo were in Spain, then the Eiffel Tower would be in Bolivia."
